# Getting th ChildNodes from an object variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, nodes, children

I've ran into a small snag with my code - below is my code:

```
var actionsAllowed = $(packet).find('actionsAllowed');
```

This returns to me the following in the firebug console:

*Object[actionsAllowed]*

Clicking "actionsAllowed" takes me into the packet and to the correct section, where I see the two listed actions.

I can expand the object and eventually see the following:

```
Object[actions]

0
    actions

remove
    remove()

attributes
    []

baseURI
    "http://localhost:9000/testget#"

childElementCount
    2

childNodes
    NodeList[ActionOne, ActionTwo]

0
    ActionOne

1
    ActionTwo

length
    2

item
    item()

iterator
    iterator()

__proto__
    NodeListPrototype { item=item(), iterator=iterator()}
```

So under the NodeList I see the correct actions.

The issue I am having is that I don't know how to get those actions out of there and listed or even just have them available as separate variables.

My attempt at getting then logging each child:

```
function getActionsAllowed() {
    var children = actionsAllowed.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            console.log(children);
        }
}
```

Problem is, ".childNodes" keeps returning as "undefined".

Is there another, better way to do this? Or is this correct but I've made a mistake?

Thank you.

Kind Regards,

Gary Shergill

EDIT:

working code for just one result:

```
var currentState = $(packet).find('currentState').text();
var actionsBanned = $(packet).find('actionsBanned').text();
```

EDIT 2:

Updated code to:

```
$(packet).find('actionsAllowed').each(function () {
    var children = this.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var action = children[i].nodeName
            console.log(action);
        }
});
```

This works =) It logs each action one by one, so it's working. Just a matter of choosing how to change the console.log() to something more useful (need to define each one seperately...).

Will create a new thread if I have trouble and link it from here.

(my related thread: [Returning Arrays and ChildNodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933748/returning-arrays-and-childnodes))

Comment: can u provide the object as such?

Comment: I've pasted what the object shows when I go into it. That is not all of it of course, it's a large number of lines, but the nodes inside "actions" is shown which should be enough?

Comment: The full object with correct values will enable all of us to provide u the answer much faster than trying to do trial/error..

Comment: Too long to paste here... it's nearly 2000 characters. 1000 characters for actions section....

Comment: jsbin/jsfiddle for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always extract the DOM nodes from the jQuery object using [`toArray`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) or [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

```
var actionsAllowed = $(packet).find('actionsAllowed').get();
```

But that's generally not necessary since the jQuery object itself implements an extensive API to manipulate the nodes.

E.g. looping over the nodes

```
$(packet).find('actionsAllowed').each(function () {
    //looping over childnodes
    $(this).children().each(function () {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```

If you just want to children of actionsAllowed nodes directly, you can also do:

```
$(packet).find('actionsAllowed > *').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: I suspect he's parsing XML, so `actionsAllowed` is probably the tag name, not a class.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah that's probably the correct assumption. I added a comment saying to ignore my modifications if my own assumptions are wrong.

Comment: Hi, that's correct, it is XML coming in, actionsAllowed isn't a class. The XML coming in has a number of tags, most of which are just single results (e.g. var currentState = $(packet).find('currentState').text();) which are no problem to deal with.

Comment: @Gary I modified the answer accordingly ;)

Comment: The e.g. line you sent, looping over the nodes, changes the return from "Object[actionsAllowed]" to just "actionsAllowed", which when clicked takes me to my XML. Is it possible for it to list the actions?

Comment: @Gary Could you show a sample of your XML? And what nodes you want to target?

Comment: Sure: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><message from='pubsub.ubuntuof' to='gary@ubuntuof' id='<<personal id>>'><event xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event'><items node='<<personal id>>'><item id='<<personal id>>'><cane xmlns='http://URL#cane'><cdetails><id><<some id>></id><currentState>Up</currentState><actionsAllowed><ActionOne/><ActionTwo/><ActionThree/></actionsAllowed><actionsBanned></actionsBanned></cdetails></cane></item></items></event>….

Comment: @Gary Glad you found an answer. You question was quite unclear however =P If you want to access the childNodes of each `actionsAllowed` you could also loop over `this.chilNodes` within the `each` callback in my example.

Comment: Haven't found the solution yet =( The ones I added which work were just for one result (just to give you an example). How do I access the childNodes of each actionsAllowed? That's the question ^^

Comment: Please see Edit 2 on the original post for the latest code and what is returned. Thanks