# Returning Arrays and ChildNodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, iteration, children

I have the following code:

```
var actionsAllowed = $(packet).find('actionsAllowed').get();

var actionArray = $(actionsAllowed).each(function () {
    var actionNodes = this.childNodes;
    var actionNumber = actionNodes.length;
    var array = new Array(actionNumber)

    for (var i = 0; i < actionNodes.length; i++) {
        var action = actionNodes[i].nodeName
        array[i] = action
        console.log(action);
    }
    return array;
});
```

This searches the packet (XML) for `"actionsAllowed"` and returns it as `"[actionsAllowed]"`.

I am then trying to create an array with each of the actions listed in the array.

The `"this"` becomes `"actionsAllowed"` without the `"[ ]"` and that allows it to return the child nodes in the form "NodeList[ActionOne, ActionTwo, ActionThree]".
I then get the length of the NodeList and create an array of that length.

I then iterate over the NodeList and add each to the array.

By the end, it returns the array as `"[ActionOne, ActionTwo, ActionThree]"`, which is great!

BUT - this is the problem:

The variable `"actionArray"` becomes `"Object[actionsAllowed]"`, instead of the array.

Any idea why this is please? I have a theory but I'm unable to fix it =(

Thank you!

Comment: `$(actionsAllowed).each(` **always** returns a jquery object. What did you expect `return array;` to do?

Comment: `actionArray = actionArray.get()` should work.

Comment: I was hoping that "return array;" would define "actionArray" as "array". This isn't the case though, is there another way to do this?

Comment: well, as it stands now, i have no idea what your end-result should be, so now i don't know what to suggest.

Comment: @Gary: When you `return` from `.each` it acts like `break` (for falsy values) and `continue` (for truthy values).  I think you may be looking for `.map()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(actionsAllowed).each` returns the first element of the iteration. You seem to want this :

```
var actionArray = [];
$(actionsAllowed).each(function () {
    var actionNodes = this.childNodes;
    var actionNumber = actionNodes.length;
    var array = new Array(actionNumber)

    for (var i = 0; i < actionNodes.length; i++) {
        var action = actionNodes[i].nodeName
        array[i] = action
        console.log(action);
    }
    actionArray.push(array);
});
```

EDIT : If what you want is a big array instead of an array of arrays, change it to

```
var actionArray = [];
$(actionsAllowed).each(function () {
    var actionNodes = this.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < actionNodes.length; i++) {
        var action = actionNodes[i].nodeName
        actionArray.push(action);
        console.log(action);
    }
});
```

Comment: Couldn't he just use `.map()`?

Comment: @megawac .map would require returning `this` to do the same thing as what dystroy is doing here. He isn't simply replacing each element in the array, he's add all the childnodes to it in addition to what was already there.

Comment: Be careful that .map doesn't really return an array too, you have at least to use .get afterwards.

Comment: This worked great, thank you! Although it does return actionArray as [[ActionOne,....,ActionThree]] but that shouldn't be much of an issue.

Comment: @Gary It's probably easy to fix but in fact I don't really understand your goal. Do you want to denormalize the array ?

Comment: I am planning to populate a div with all actions available for a call, which updates when the call terminates, etc. So this "array" of actions will be used to populate the div, which each value of the array being clickable and doing a different thing.

Comment: @Gary Is the code I gave in the edit what you were looking for ?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much =) Been spending hours on this

Comment: @plalx Seems worthy of an answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative:

```
var actionArray = $('actionsAllowed > *').map(function (el) { 
    return el.nodeName; 
}).get();
```

Comment: +1 Now that we have the entire specification, this is the best solution.